# How to transfer files from on zip to another without decrompressing

Tags: python-3.x, zip

The title says it all, I'm trying to transfer a list of files from one zip to another without the need to de-compress then re-compress the files.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Just generally or specifically in python?

Comment: specifically in python

Comment: Well, not to say it can't be done, but it would be much easier just to unzip to a temp folder and copy, then delete the files in the temp directory. If you are absolutely sure you must do it without unzipping the archive, the only way that I can think of is to deal with the file structure of a zip file, which is going to get really messy if you aren't used to dealing with files on a byte level. If you do want to go with that, you may want to look [here](https://users.cs.jmu.edu/buchhofp/forensics/formats/pkzip.html)

Comment: I'm pretty sure this cannot be done by using a public API, but it could be done by replicating (and adjusting) the zipfile.Zipfile.writestr method in your code.  However, that would result in a pretty fragile end result as you'd be relying on private details of the zipfile implementation and those details can change between python versions (and could even change in bugfix releases).  Because of that it is safer to use the public API and recompress the data.

Answer (score 0):

Yes as danielu13 said just unzip to temp folder and copy. Also you may wanto include more specifics into you question (code samples, directory structures etc. 
ps @danielu13 why not post your comment as an answer? I'm new here so there could be a good reason.